# How to copy a file in Linux when the original file name has 2+ terms?

Tags: linux, putty

I'm new to Linux, so I was wondering what I do in this type of a situation?

For example, my original file is called "My File", and I want to copy it to "New". Whenever I do the following:

```
    cp My File New
```

I get the following:

```
    cp: target `New' is not a directory
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: `cp My\ File New`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying Files with Spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359625/copying-files-with-spaces)

Comment: Use tab-completion to get the shell to complete the rest of the filename with proper quoting.  e.g. `cp My<tab>` -> `cp My\ File`.  Then you can type the dest filename.  Also, this belongs on AskUbuntu, unix.SE, or superuser, not SO.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "escape" the space character.

```
cp My\ File New
```

Answer (score 1):

since your file name is having space in it(I assume you have created valid file with name "My File"),  you need to copy it like below-

```
 cp "My File" New
```